# update excel autofilter with newly inserted row as visible

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that inserts a new row within a named range with an input. It inserts alphabetically. My problem is that while the row is visible, the autofilter doesn't update this new row as visible. How can I use VBA to update the new row as visible?

Here is the code for adding the new row.

```
Dim sNewName As String
Dim lPosition As Long
Dim rCompList As Range

Set rCompList = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Companies2")

sNewName = InputBox("Enter name of new company")
On Error Resume Next
lPosition = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sNewName, rCompList, 2)
On Error GoTo 0
Rows(lPosition + 2).Insert
Range("A" & lPosition + 2).Value = sNewName
```

Here is a recorded macro of making a company visible within the autofilter. I added "Rotork"

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$A$160").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ABS", "Accurate", "AGI", "Alexander Ryan Marine", "Alimak", "Audubon", _
        "Relevant", "Rig Net", "Rotork", "Seatrax", "Solar", "Tampnet", "Third Coast", _
        "Total Daily POB", "Trinity", "USCG"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

To be clear: since the array of companies visible will change from time to time, I need to find a way to store the array of visible companies as a variable and then add the new company to that array afterwards, or something that achieves the same goal

I have tried to find other related answers but nothing matches or works.

Comment: Just add the new name to the range you use in the autofilter and call that code after adding the new name   
`Sheets("Sheet4").Range("$A:$A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "ABS", "Accurate", "AGI", "Alexander Ryan Marine", "Alimak", "Audubon", _
            "Relevant", "Rig Net", "Rotork", "Seatrax", "Solar", "Tampnet", "Third Coast", _
            "Total Daily POB", "Trinity", "USCG", sNewName), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: `Set rEmpList = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Companies2")` ?? Shouldn't that be `Set rCompList ..`

Comment: This is going to be an unknown array, since people will change what's visible them from time to time, so i can't just add it as it is unknown as far as VBA goes. Yes, it is actually rCompList, I did some editing when posting.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but 2 is not a valid value for the 3rd argument to the `MATCH()` function, only -1,0 or 1 are valid

Comment: lol, yeah I'm fairly new to vba. I was trying to fix the alphabetical insert. thanks for the clarification

Comment: Does the `Range("Companies2")` include a header row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While CDP1802 was close it didn't quite get what I needed. Here is the solution I received with the help of GPT4. This will save the names that are visible within the auto filter. it will ask for a new company then insert and sort within the named range all while keeping and data outside of the named range intact.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddAndSortCompany()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCompanies As Range
    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim companyName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Set the worksheet and named range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngCompanies = ws.Range("Companies")

    ' Get the user input for the new company name
    companyName = InputBox("Enter the new company name:", "Add Company")

    ' Check if the user provided input
    If companyName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No company name provided. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Step 1: Remember everything that is visible in the auto filter
    Dim visibleCompanies As Collection
    Set visibleCompanies = New Collection

    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
        '' Loop through the cells in column A
        'For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        '    If ws.Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
        '        ' Add the visible value to the collection
        '        visibleCompanies.Add ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        '    End If
        'Next i
        For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ' Check if the cell value is the new company's name
            If StrComp(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, companyName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ' Display a message and exit the sub
                MsgBox "Cell " & ws.Cells(i, 1).Address(False, False) & " already has this company"
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Select
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf ws.Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
                ' Add the visible value to the collection
                visibleCompanies.Add ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    ' Step 2: Insert a new row at the bottom of the named range
    ws.Rows(rngCompanies.Row + rngCompanies.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Insert

    ' Step 3: Put the new company in the A cell of the newly inserted row
    ws.Cells(rngCompanies.Row + rngCompanies.Rows.Count, rngCompanies.Column).Value = companyName

    ' Expand the named range to include the new row
    Set rngCompanies = ws.Range(rngCompanies, rngCompanies.Offset(1, 0))
    ThisWorkbook.Names("Companies").RefersTo = rngCompanies

    ' Sort the named range alphabetically
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rngCompanies.Columns(1), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange rngCompanies.Resize(, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Step 4: Add the new company to the list of visible items in the auto filter
    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
        ' Display visible companies before making changes
        ' MsgBox "Visible companies before changes: " & Join(CollectionToArray(visibleCompanies), ", ")

        visibleCompanies.Add companyName

        ' Clear the current filter
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False

        ' Reapply the AutoFilter
        ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter

        ' Create an array for the filter criteria and populate it with the visibleCompanies collection
        Dim filterCriteria() As Variant
        ReDim filterCriteria(1 To visibleCompanies.Count)
        Dim index As Long
        For index = 1 To visibleCompanies.Count
            filterCriteria(index) = CStr(visibleCompanies.Item(index))
        Next index

        ' Apply the filter using the array
        ws.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=True
    End If
'rngCompanies, companyName


' Find and select cell with value of new company in named range

For Each cell In rngCompanies.Cells
    If cell.Value = companyName Then
        cell.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
    
' If the value is not found, show a message box
If cell Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox "Value not found in named range."
End If


'MsgBox "New company added successfully, including associated rows."
End Sub









Function CollectionToArray(coll As Collection) As Variant
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim arr(1 To coll.Count)

    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        arr(i) = coll(i)
    Next i

    CollectionToArray = arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Transpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose) to create an array from a range that you can use in the filter,

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim rCompList As Range
    Dim sNewName As String, lastrow As Long
   
    sNewName = Trim(InputBox("Enter name of new company"))
    If Len(sNewName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox sNewName & "Blank entry", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
     ' check not existing
    Set rCompList = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Companies2")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rCompList, sNewName) > 0 Then
        MsgBox sNewName & " exists already", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' insert at top assume row 1 is header
    rCompList.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    rCompList.Cells(2, 1) = sNewName
    ' sort list
    With rCompList.Parent.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rCompList.Cells(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rCompList
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    ' update filter
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' or ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:A" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, _
         Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(rCompList), _
         Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
         
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks CDP1802, This kind of works. I guess I didn't specify that there is other stuff in column A that isn't a part of the named range, that stuff disappears after execution. Also, there is data in the other columns that are associated with each row that doesn't move when things get shifted with in column A

Comment: @CForester _stuff disappears_ ? Do you means it gets filters out ? So you want other stuff in the filter that isn't in the Companies2 range ?

Comment: yes, there are a few things above and below this named range I'm filtering in column A that get filtered out as well. And I still need this info on the sheet

Comment: @Cforester  how can they be identified, is there a pattern to them ? Can they have their own named range ?

Comment: I can give them named ranges if that helps, there would be 2 additional I would need to add. Again, the column data associated with all of these named ranges should be preserved. I would specify how far out the column data goes but this can be added to very easily by those using this worksheet. Hope that helps